# Descargo un Excel dentro de un zip pero el Excel viene vacio

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

actualmente estoy creando y descargando un `.zip`, el cual contiene imágenes y un Excel.

Las imágenes se descargan perfectamente, pero el problema está en el Excel, el cual se ve que está dentro de la carpeta, pero cuando lo abro no trae los datos que quiero.

El Excel debería contener datos de una tabla del `HTML`, pero no estoy pudiendo llenarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
Numero de Tramite   Nombre  Apellido    Sexo  Doc  Ejemplar  FechaN     FechaE      Codigo
1111111111          John    Salchichon  M     111    A       01/01/1999 01/01/1999   200
```

Éste es el codigo del .zip, voy a omitir el codigo de las imagenes ya que no lo creo relevante.

```
using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()){
  using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(connection))
                    {
                        consulta = "SELECT entrega_tr, numTramite_tr, nombre_tr, apellido_tr, sexo_tr, documento_tr, ejemplar_tr, fechaNac_tr, fechaEmision_tr, cod_tr from transportista WHERE entrega_tr = @entrega GROUP BY entrega_tr";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, cn);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrega", entrega);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cn.Open();

                        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    dt.TableName = "Transportista";

                    using (XLWorkbook excel = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                         excel.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                        //hoja.ColumnsUsed().AdjustToContents();

                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            //excel.SaveAs(stream);

                            var excelTrans = File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");                            
                            byte[] excelByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(excelTrans.ToString());
                            zip.AddEntry("Transportista.xls", excelByte);
                            zip.Save(stream);
                            bytes = stream.ToArray();
                            return File(bytes, "application/zip", nombreZip);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

Básicamente lo que quiero hacer con el `XLWorkbook` es crear el Excel, agregarle los datos que traigo de la base de datos, y luego convertirlo en `byte[]` asi puedo guardarlo dentro de `zip.AddEntry()` ya que de otra manera no me deja guardarlo.

Y ésto es lo que se ve en mi Excel cuando lo abro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Simplemente una linea que dice:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult

**Edit:**

Asi descargo las imagenes separado del Excel:

```
            listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
            consulta = "SELECT p.Pedido, e.Path from Pedido p INNER JOIN Entrega e ON p.Entrega = e.Entrega WHERE p.Entrega = '" + entrega + "'";// GROUP by e.Path";
            listaPedidos = TraerDirectoriosImagenesPedidos(consulta);

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
                {
                    // imgAndroid\2022\09\06\imgas....
                    nombreImagen = lista.getPathImagen().Split("/");
                    var archivo_nombre = nombreImagen[5];
                    var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"wwwroot" + lista.getImagenes());
                    zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
                }

                var nombreZip = "ImagenesPedido" + entrega + ".zip";

                using (output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(output);
                    bytes = output.ToArray();
                    return File(bytes, "application/zip", nombreZip);
                }
            }
```

Y asi es como descargo el Excel por separado del `.zip`

```
        string consulta;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        byte[] bytes;

    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";" + ";username=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";"))
    {
        consulta = "SELECT entrega_tr, numTramite_tr, nombre_tr, apellido_tr, sexo_tr, documento_tr, ejemplar_tr, fechaNac_tr, fechaEmision_tr, cod_tr from transportista WHERE entrega_tr = @entrega GROUP BY entrega_tr";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrega", entrega);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cn.Open();

        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
    }


    dt.TableName = "Transportista";

    using (XLWorkbook excel = new XLWorkbook())
    {
        excel.Worksheets.Add(dt);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            excel.SaveAs(stream);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Transportista " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");
                 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Primero logra que se guarde el excel o se descargue. Después, sabiendo que funciona la "exportación a Excel", lo incluyes en el Zip.

Comment: El excel si lo descargo por fuera del zip se descarga correctamente

Comment: por lo tanto, intenta mover el excel afuera del zip para que lo tengas listo cuando toque ponerlo al zip.

Comment: Mi problema tambien está que no sé transfromrar un FileResult en byte[], asi lo puedo agregar sin problemas

Comment: Acomoda la pregunta colocando los datos que mencionas y te doy una posible respuesta.